# Python: Not able to parse email message piped to stdin

Tags: python, email, stdin

I'm piping an email message from Pigeonhole to the Python script using Sieve filters which looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import email

input = sys.stdin

#For manual testing 
#input=open(sys.argv[2]).read()

msg=email.message_from_string(input)
```

But it fails with the error below

```
Sep 21 11:41:24 lmtp: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 21 11:41:24 lmtp: Error: File "message-processor.py", line 11, in <module>
Sep 21 11:41:24 lmtp: Error: msg=email.message_from_string(input)
Sep 21 11:41:24 lmtp: Error: File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/email/__init__.py", line 57, in message_from_string
Sep 21 11:41:24 lmtp: Error: return Parser(*args, **kws).parsestr(s)
Sep 21 11:41:24 lmtp: Error: File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/email/parser.py", line 82, in parsestr
Sep 21 11:41:24 lmtp: Error: return self.parse(StringIO(text), headersonly=headersonly)
Sep 21 11:41:24 lmtp: Error: TypeError: expected read buffer, file found
```

It works fine when i use email saved as a file but not piped in.

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have switched to `email.parser` which do the job

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import email
import email.parser

input = sys.stdin

#For manual testing 
#input=open(sys.argv[2]).read()

msg = email.parser.Parser().parse(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting (`TypeError: expected read buffer, file found`) is clear: The function `message_from_string` expects a string (as the name suggests), while you're giving it a file (`sys.stdin`). If you want to enable piping you need to first save the incoming text as a string, and then pass it on to `message_from_string`. Something along the lines of:

```
import sys
import os
import email

# Save the piped input as a string
s = '\n'.join(line for line in sys.stdin)

msg = email.message_from_string(s)
```

Comment: That works fine as well other solution which I found